# JavaScript. Alerting a string

Tags: javascript, string, class, alert

I am a newbie at JavaScript. So, I was trying to solve an exercise -  announcing movie showtimes. I have already checked what's wrong with it, but i found nothing. When I open the index.html file nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cinema</title>
    <script src="cinema.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

cinema.js

```
var movie1={
    name: "Star Wars: Force Awakens",
    showtimes: ["3:00pm","7:00pm","11:00pm"],
    genre: "Cult Classic",
    rating: 2
};
var movie2={
    name: "Doctor Strange",
    showtimes: ["5:00pm","9:00pm"],
    genre: "Action",
    rating: 5
};

window.onload = function (){
    var nextShowing=getNextShowing(movie1);
    alert(nextShowing);
    nextShowing=getNextShowing(movie2);
    alert(nextShowing);

}
function getNextShowing(movie){
    var now=new Date().getTime();

    for(var i=0;i<movie.showtimes.length;i++){
        var showtime = getTimeFromString(movie.showtimes[i]);
        if((showtime-now)>0) {
            return "Next showing of "+movie.name+" is "+movie.showtimes[i];
    }
}
    return null;
}

function getTimeFromString(timeString){
    var theTime = new Date();
    var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(p?) /);
    theTime.setHours( parselnt(time[1]) +(time[3] ? 12 : 0) );
    theTime.setMinutes( parseInt(time[2])|| 0 );
    return theTime.getTime();
}
```

Where might be a problem?

UPD:

```
function getNextShowing(movie){
    var now=new Date().getTime();

    for(var i=0;i<movie.showtimes.length;i++){
        var showtime = getTimeFromString(movie.showtimes[i]);
        if((showtime-now)>0) {
            return "Next showing of "+movie.name+" is "+movie.showtimes[i];
    }
}
    return null;
}

function getTimeFromString(timeString){
    var theTime = new Date();
    var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(p?) /);
    theTime.setHours( parseInt(time[1])+(time[3] ?12 : 0) );
    theTime.setMinutes(parseInt(time[2])|| 0 );
    return theTime.getTime();
}
```

still nothing happens

Comment: check the spelling of `parseInt`

Comment: for web pages, browser developer tools console should always be the first step in debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. parseInt function name was not correct. Please replace `parselnt` with `parseInt`
2. Match pattern was not correct. Here is the updated one

   ```
   var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(?::)(\d+)(am|pm)/);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your spelling of parseInt (you have it written as parselnt).

As you continue to learn Javascript, one of your first ports of call for debugging should be to open your browser's developer tools/console.

For example, in Google Chrome you can do this by pressing Ctrl + Shift + i.

The console should provide detail on any runtime errors that your javascript encounters, which will be your first step to diagnosing your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a typo here `theTime.setHours( parselnt(time[1]) +(time[3] ? 12 : 0) );` It should be `parseInt`.